# select all xml child nodes that start with a string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmldocument

I am using C# .

I have an xml node with child nodes as follows :

```
<PriceID>32</PriceID>
<Store_1> 344</Store_1>
      <Store_32> 343 </Store_32>
```

I would like to select all nodes that start with **Store**

Is there a way I can do it ?

I know there is a way to select nodes with specific names ..

```
  XmlNodeList xnList = quote.SelectNodes("Store_1");
```

Does anyone know what will help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq2Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var stores = xDoc.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Store"))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 Thanks L.B ! Do you have a solution using xpath & c# ? We dont use linq at all right now.. & it might be odd to use linq only for this .

Comment: @PowerCoder that kind of XML with numbered suffixes on element names is a sure sign of really poor XML design.  Change it if you can.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth : Thats just a quick example to help people understand my problem, That is not the xml I have . Hope the downvote was not for the structure of the xml.

Comment: No worries, no downvote from me.  I'm just dealing with a similar issue now with a bunch of new XML developers that consider it "proper" to have every node have a unique name (by adding a _xxx number suffix).  It really makes using the document difficult for the very reason you're running into.